# Not able to send array in Jquery - Giving NetworkError 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function, I have 2 types string & array, If i pass only string type, it hits the controller and works fine, but if i pass array along with it, I get the network error 400 bad request. How do i go about it. Code is as follows

```
function saveFocusGrp() {

    var focusName = window.prompt('Please enter the focus group name:');
    var enteredFocusList = [];
    enteredFocusList = focuslist;   // here focuslist is declared globally and is assigned the value in other function which I'm getting it in this function it will be in the form abc,def,xyz 

    alert("focus Name====>" + focusName);
    alert("focus List====> " + enteredFocusList); // I get the values here in alert too

    $.ajax({
        url : '/DataWeb/saveFocusData',
        type : 'get',
        dataType : 'json',
        data :  { focusGroupName : focusName, focusList : enteredFocusList },
        success : function(map) {
            console.log(map);
            var $out = $('#focusGroupName');
            $out.html(map.successMsg);

        }



    });

}
```

Error i get in firebug is: NetworkError: 400 Bad Request

Home controller code :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveFocusData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void saveFocusData(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
            @RequestParam("focusGroupName") String focusGroupName,
            @RequestParam("focusList") List focusList) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Inside home controller============");
        Gson json = new Gson();
        res.setContentType("application/json");
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String successMsg="";
        map.put("successMsg", successMsg);
        res.getWriter().print(json.toJson(map));    
}
```

Comment: I assume the problem is in how your controller interprets the `focusList` param. Please give us your controller part.

Comment: Maybe it is because you have get in your type. Did you try having it with post?

Comment: Yes.. I tried with post too.. it gave me the same error

Comment: try escaping the data when sending, and unescaping when recieiving.
also: use json functions to stringify and unstrigify your data.